# Kubernetes + Socket.io: Pod client -> LoadBalancer service SSL issues

Tags: node.js, ssl, networking, kubernetes, socket.io

I have a socket.io-based node.js deployment on my Kubernetes cluster with a LoadBalancer-type service through Digital Ocean. The service uses SSL termination using a certificate uploaded to DO.

I've written a pod which acts as a health check to ensure that clients are still able to connect. This pod is node.js using the `socket.io-client` package, and it connects via the public domain name for the service. When I run the container locally, it connects just fine, but when I run the container as a pod in the same cluster as the service, the health check can't connect. When I shell into the pod, or any pod really, and try `wget my-socket.domain.com`, I get an SSL handshake error "wrong version number".

Any idea why a client connection from outside the cluster works, a client connection out of the cluster to a normal server works, but a client connection from a pod in the cluster to the public domain name of the service doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) to route traffic from a Load-Balancer to a Service.

The flow of traffic looks like this:

```
INTERNET -> LoadBalancer -> [ Ingress Controller -> Service]
```

**If you want to use SSL:**

You can provision your own SSL certificate and create a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) to hold it. You can then refer to the Secret in an Ingress specification to create an HTTP(S) load balancer that uses the certificate.

You can deploy an ingress controller like nginx using  following instruction: [ingress-controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

Comment: I found the real issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the issue is with how kube-proxy handles LoadBalancer-type services and requests to it from inside the cluster. Turns out, when the service is created, it adds iptables entries that causes requests inside the cluster skip the load balancer completely, which becomes an issue when the load balancer also handles SSL termination. There is a workaround, which is to add a `loadbalancer-hostname` annotation which forces all connections to use the load balancer. AWS tends not to have this problem because they automatically apply the workaround to their service configurations, but Digital Ocean does not.

Here are some more details:

https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/controllers/services/annotations.md